# Dividing data frame by column vector

Tags: r, dataframe, division

I have a data frame and I have a column from another data frame. I would like to divide every column of the first data frame by the column from another data frame. I can't seem to find a good answer without turning to matrices or doing a lot of work.

```
Type1 <- c(12,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Type2 <- c(29,4,0,1,0,1,0,0)
Type3 <- c(49,6,1,0,1,1,0,0)

Count <- c(897,525,220,150,183,106,129,89)
Count

df1 <- data.frame(Type1, Type2, Type3)

df2 <- data.frame(Count)


df1/df2$Count
```

Gives me [image]

I want all Type1 values divided by 897 and Type2 values divided by 525, and so on

Answer above gives incorrect values.

In Numpy it's so easy but can't find a solution in R.

Comment: Try with `df1/df2$col1[col(df1)]`

Comment: Please include a  reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, worked like a charm. The code looks a bit counter-intuitive though. Why are we indexing at the end?

Comment: It is not really needed i.e. `col` returns the column index to replicate the values.  But, here we can make use of recycling as well

Answer (score 1):

Based on the updated data, it seems to be dividing each corresponding value of 'df2' 'Count' with the corresponding column of 'df1'.  So, we just replicate the 'Count'

```
> df2$Count[col(df1)]
 [1] 897 897 897 897 897 897 897 897 525 525 525 525 525 525 525 525 220 220 220 220 220 220 220 220
```

to make the lengths same and then divide by 'df1'

```
df1/df2$Count[col(df1)]
     Type1       Type2       Type3
1 0.013377926 0.055238095 0.222727273
2 0.001114827 0.007619048 0.027272727
3 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.004545455
4 0.000000000 0.001904762 0.000000000
5 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.004545455
6 0.000000000 0.001904762 0.004545455
7 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
8 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
```

Or take the `t`ranspose and divide

```
t(t(df1)/df2$Count)
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. The solution in your comment worked though.

Comment: @YuryMoskaltsov can you tell me why it is not working.  The `(1:6)` I showed is just a vector to reproduce it.

Comment: @YuryMoskaltsov do you have a `data.frame` or is it something else.  It works on the mtcars example

Comment: I have updated the question to include dataframe above.

Comment: After some thought. I would like to divide each row of the first data frame by a corresponding value of that row in the column of the other dataframe. Hopw that makes sense.

Comment: @YuryMoskaltsov please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

There is some conflicting information in the question and comments so to be clear we assume you want to divide each column of df1 by Count so the three columns of the result should equal Type1 / Count, Type2 / Count and Type3 / Count respectively where Type1, Type2, Type3 and Count are defined in the question.  We also assume that the calculation should be in terms of df1 and df2.

We can use /, sweep, Map, apply or mutate/across:

```
res1 <- df1 / df2$Count

res2 <- sweep(df1, 1, df2$Count, `/`)

res3 <- as.data.frame(Map(`/`, df1, df2))

res4 <- as.data.frame(apply(df1, 2, `/`, df2$Count))

library(dplyr)
res5 <- df1 %>% mutate(across(, `/`, df2$Count))


# check
res0 <- data.frame(Type1 = Type1 / Count, Type2 = Type2 / Count, Type3 = Type3 / Count)

identical(res1, res0)
## [1] TRUE

identical(res2, res0)
## [1] TRUE

identical(res3, res0)
## [1] TRUE

identical(res4, res0)
## [1] TRUE

identical(res5, res0)
## [1] TRUE
```